# Porque obtengo este error usando Typescript en Context API?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, context

El error aparece cuando paso el mouse por `{props.children}` qué esta subrayado en rojo y dice `La propiedad 'children' no existe en el tipo '{}'`
Código:

```
import React, { ReactNode, useState } from 'react';
import Todo from '../models/todo';

type TodosContextObj = {
  items: Todo[];
  addTodo: (text: string) => void;
  removeTodo: (id: string) => void;
};

export const TodosContext = React.createContext<TodosContextObj>({
  items: [],
  addTodo: () => {},
  removeTodo: (id: string) => {},
});

const TodosContextProvider: React.FC = props => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([]);

  const addTodoHandler = (todoText: string) => {
    const newTodo = new Todo(todoText);

    setTodos(prevTodos => {
      return prevTodos.concat(newTodo);
    });
  };

  const removeTodoHandler = (todoId: string) => {
    setTodos(prevTodos => {
      return prevTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== todoId);
    });
  };

  const contextValue: TodosContextObj = {
    items: todos,
    addTodo: addTodoHandler,
    removeTodo: removeTodoHandler,
  };

  return (
    <TodosContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </TodosContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default TodosContextProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver el conflicto creando un type para la props:

```
import React, { ReactNode, useState } from 'react';
import Todo from '../models/todo';

type TodosContextObj = {
  items: Todo[];
  addTodo: (text: string) => void;
  removeTodo: (id: string) => void;
};

export const TodosContext = React.createContext<TodosContextObj>({
  items: [],
  addTodo: () => {},
  removeTodo: (id: string) => {},
});

type Props = {
  children: any;
};

const TodosContextProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([]);

  const addTodoHandler = (todoText: string) => {
    const newTodo = new Todo(todoText);

    setTodos(prevTodos => {
      return prevTodos.concat(newTodo);
    });
  };

  const removeTodoHandler = (todoId: string) => {
    setTodos(prevTodos => {
      return prevTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== todoId);
    });
  };

  const contextValue: TodosContextObj = {
    items: todos,
    addTodo: addTodoHandler,
    removeTodo: removeTodoHandler,
  };

  return (
    <TodosContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </TodosContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default TodosContextProvider;
```